# Movable camera articulating spring-loaded boom arm like a dentist's examination light

Tags: screw-mount

I do high volume product photography on a table top. I would like to have a long articulating arm capable of holding a DSLR that I can move around atop the subject. I don't want something like the Manfrotto magic arm because you have to manually loosen and tighten each joint every time you want to reposition nor is it long enough. I want something around 36-40" extendable length like a light in a dentist's office that is shined over the patient in the chair - they can just grab it to reposition and angle it and then let it go and it stays in the air. This way I can have two hands free to reposition or swap out subjects and then resume my photography process. I need something heavy duty that will withstand 1000 photos per day worth of moving around. Also I need the base fixed or mounted in place.

Is there any term for what I'm describing and where can I buy something like this?
I saw a couple YouTube videos of guys who built their own spring-loaded camera arm jigs but I'm looking for something commercially available. If that doesn't exist, then something I envision something like an overhead gantry setup with X and Y axis movement and then the camera hangs down for the Z axis with a ball joint like a gimble so I can angle the camera. I'm looking for manual movement and not anything computer programmed / robotic.

Are there setups available with something like a crane and pan/tilt head?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRkdNH5fxRE&ab_channel=PhilVandelay
and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bm5QBTpMy0

Comment: Not for a camera, but transforming a [standard VESA swing arm display mount](https://www.amazon.com/Single-Monitor-Mount-Articulating-Adjustable/dp/B07T3KCQ94) isn't difficult, you need a plate with 4 holes (for the VESA screws) and one  hole in the center (Camera screw or Arca-Swiss quick release clamp)

Comment: Thanks a gas spring arm would be the smoothest. But that's too short (I need about double the length) and I need up and down Z-axis travel for full range of motion. It doesnt' look like any gas spring camera boom arms are commercially available

Comment: The term you want to search for is "camera jib".

Comment: You should post that as an answer as it is what he should be looking for.

Comment: Something like the "Articulating Arm", https://www.amazon.com/Articulating-Overhead-Compatible-Photography-Recording/dp/B09Y24B3X9/ref=sr_1_20 ,? That model looks a bit flimsy, and has max weight of 5 pounds (2 kg). BTW, on a similar arm used for magnifier/lamp combo, I've added rubber bands cut from inner tubes to the springs to help sustain weight of heavier LED bulb.

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for but on a smaller scale. I saw a manufacturer carry them in 3-5 ft lenghts but they're discontinued